# Java code not executing as expected

Tags: java

I've written some Java code, as shown below, but it isn't behaving as I expected. Right near the bottom, starting from the line `if (upgrade == "Y")`. I did a test, I entered `Y` but this line did not execute. Could you please help me figure out why this behaviour occurred?

```
import java.io.*;

class P4
{
public static int get_price(String day_of_week, String age_group)
{
    int price=0;

    if (day_of_week == "WD")
    {
        if (age_group == "adult")
            price = 66;

        else if (age_group == "child")
            price=48;

        else
            price = 32;
    }
    else
    {
        if (age_group == "adult")
            price = 72;

        else if (age_group == "child")
            price=52;

        else
            price = 36;
    }

    return price;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String adult2=null;
    String child2=null;
    String senior2=null;
    String day_of_week=null;
    String upgrade=null;


    System.out.println("Enter Number of Adult Ticket:");
    BufferedReader adult1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        adult2 = adult1.readLine();     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Number of Child Ticket:");
    BufferedReader child1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        child2 = child1.readLine();     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Number of Senior Ticket:");
    BufferedReader senior1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        senior2 = senior1.readLine();       
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Choose Weekday or Weekend Pass (WD/WE):");
    BufferedReader day_of_week1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        day_of_week = day_of_week1.readLine();      
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Upgrade to Express Pass (Y/N):");
    BufferedReader upgrade1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        upgrade = upgrade1.readLine();      
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int adult = Integer.parseInt(adult2);
    int child = Integer.parseInt(child2);
    int senior = Integer.parseInt(senior2);

    int total_a = adult * get_price(day_of_week, "adult");
    int total_c = child * get_price(day_of_week, "child");
    int total_s = senior * get_price(day_of_week, "senior");

    int total_price = total_a + total_c + total_s;

    int total_people = adult + child + senior;

    int upgrade_price = 0;

    if (upgrade == "Y")
    {
        if (day_of_week == "WD")
        {
            upgrade_price = total_people * 30;
        }
        else
        {
            upgrade_price = total_people * 68;
        }
    }
    else
        upgrade_price = 0;


    int price = upgrade_price + total_price;

    System.out.println("The total price is $" + price);

}}
```

Comment: == is used just for comparing the references the in your case equals() will be the right choice.... the debugging feature of your IDE (if at all you are using any) will make your life much easier in these situations..... You will not only understand the working of your program but it will also reduce the time taken in solving errors......

Comment: I really, really recommend Joshua Block: "Effective Java" for learning java idioms such as how to compare objects. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the .equal.. So else if (age_group.equals("child")

Check out the .equals() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

and the .equalsIgnoreCase() method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

```
import java.io.*;

class P4
{
  public static int get_price(String day_of_week, String age_group)
  {
    int price=0;

    if (day_of_week.equals("WD"))
    {
      if (age_group.equals("adult"))
        price = 66;
      else if (age_group.equals("child"))
        price=48;
      else
        price = 32;
    }
    else
    {
      if (age_group.equals("adult"))
        price = 72;
      else if (age_group.equals("child"))
        price=52;
      else
        price = 36;
  }

  return price;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot compare strings with ==, you need to use [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
if("Y".equals(upgrade))
```

(I tend to put the constant first, to handle the case where `upgrade == null`)

Answer (score 4):

In [java string comparison](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html)

> ```
>     String s = "something", t = "maybe something else";
>     if (s == t)      // Legal, but usually WRONG.
>     if (s.equals(t)) // RIGHT
>     if (s > t)    // ILLEGAL
>     if (s.compareTo(t) > 0) // CORRECT>
> ```

So in your case, use:

```
if(upgrade.equals("Y")) { 
      //your codes
}
```

---

```
import java.io.*;

class P4
{
public static int get_price(String day_of_week, String age_group)
{
    int price=0;

    if (day_of_week.equals("WD"))
    {
        if (age_group.equals("adult"))
            price = 66;

        else if (age_group.equals("child"))
            price=48;

        else
            price = 32;
    }
    else
    {
        if (age_group.equals("adult"))
            price = 72;

        else if (age_group.equals("child"))
            price=52;

        else
            price = 36;
    }

    return price;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String adult2=null;
    String child2=null;
    String senior2=null;
    String day_of_week=null;
    String upgrade=null;


    System.out.println("Enter Number of Adult Ticket:");
    BufferedReader adult1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        adult2 = adult1.readLine();     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Number of Child Ticket:");
    BufferedReader child1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        child2 = child1.readLine();     
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Number of Senior Ticket:");
    BufferedReader senior1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        senior2 = senior1.readLine();       
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Choose Weekday or Weekend Pass (WD/WE):");
    BufferedReader day_of_week1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        day_of_week = day_of_week1.readLine();      
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Upgrade to Express Pass (Y/N):");
    BufferedReader upgrade1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try
    {
        upgrade = upgrade1.readLine();      
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int adult = Integer.parseInt(adult2);
    int child = Integer.parseInt(child2);
    int senior = Integer.parseInt(senior2);

    int total_a = adult * get_price(day_of_week, "adult");
    int total_c = child * get_price(day_of_week, "child");
    int total_s = senior * get_price(day_of_week, "senior");

    int total_price = total_a + total_c + total_s;

    int total_people = adult + child + senior;

    int upgrade_price = 0;

    if (upgrade.equals("Y"))
    {
        if (day_of_week.equals("WD"))
        {
            upgrade_price = total_people * 30;
        }
        else
        {
            upgrade_price = total_people * 68;
        }
    }
    else
        upgrade_price = 0;


    int price = upgrade_price + total_price;

    System.out.println("The total price is $" + price);

}}
```

Answer (score 2):

for equality condition in string you need `equal` method.

use

```
"Y".equals(upgrade); //is a good idea
```

instead of

```
upgrade == "Y"
```

Since Strings are objects, the **equals(Object) method will return true if two Strings have the same objects. The == operator will only be true if two String references point to the same underlying String object.** Hence two Strings representing the same content will be equal when tested by the equals(Object) method, but will only by equal when tested with the == operator if they are actually the same object.

refer http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/

Comment: We must place constant value first for string comparision 
e.g.

Comment: okay...but in my public static int get_price() if day_of_week == "WD"  works. any idea why?

Comment: try upgrade == "Yes" it wont work The == operator will only be true if two String references point to the same underlying String object

Answer (score 0):

I notised that your `update` variable is String, thus you should use:

```
    if (upgrade.compareTo("Y") == 0) {
        //your code
    }
```

this is the correct way to compare Strings.

Comment: I just tested your code with the correction from above and it worked. You could also use upgrade.compareToIgnoreCase("Y") == 0